# Can CMake build subprojects (with benefits)?

Tags: makefile, cmake, project-structure

I have some huge project that is being compiled in CMake.
It is developed for quite a long time, have 8000+ source/header files (over 500Mbytes, over 500 CMakefile.txt files).

They use directory structure like this

```
PROJECT_NAME
  src
    / subdir_name
    / other_dir_name
    / some_different_dir
    / MY_SPECIFIC_DIR             <---
    / yet_another_dir
   build
```

and build it out-source, like this:

```
name@host:~/PROJECT_NAME/build> cmake ../src
name@host:~/PROJECT_NAME/build> make all
```

then it's build as one BIG binary (details are not important).

---

I cannot touch anything else, just content of `MY_SPECIFIC_DIR` - it's source and CMake files.
So, I have source code in `MY_SPECIFIC_DIR` *tweak CMakefile.txt files* ***somehow*** and would like to build it like this:

```
name@host:~/PROJECT_NAME/build_specific> cmake ../src/MY_SPECIFIC_DIR
name@host:~/PROJECT_NAME/build_specific> make all
```

This should build things in `MY_SPECIFIC_DIR` into single binary **with some few links to other subprojects**. But also (obviously) don't change anything about how whole project is compiled.

### My question is:

**Is my desired setup**
***posible***
**using CMake?**
Can I somehow test in `CMakeFile.txt` that it is root project and build it in different way then when it is builded as a whole?

---

Unless, I have to resort to different means and use standard `make` for this.
I don't know CMake so I'm hoping for ***YES/NO*** anwer, preferable even for technique how to achieve this. And then learn the CMake and do it.

Also, I must use CMake version 2.6.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basic concept is to use

```
if (CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR)
   ... code for stand-alone app
else()
   ... what was in this file before
endif()
```